# how can i find out the min and max values of the productID from the below data using xpath expression

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:nor="http://schemas.cordys.com/NorthwindMetadata">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <nor:UpdateOrder_x0020_Details reply="yes" commandUpdate="no" preserveSpace="no" batchUpdate="no">
         <nor:tuple>
            <nor:new>
               <nor:Order_x0020_Details qAccess="0" qConstraint="0" qInit="0" qValues="">
                  <nor:OrderID>11113</nor:OrderID>
                  <nor:ProductID>43</nor:ProductID>
                  <nor:UnitPrice>36.0000</nor:UnitPrice>
                  <nor:Quantity>25</nor:Quantity>
                  <nor:Discount>0</nor:Discount>
               </nor:Order_x0020_Details>
            </nor:new>
         </nor:tuple>
         <nor:tuple>
            <nor:new>
               <nor:Order_x0020_Details qAccess="0" qConstraint="0" qInit="0" qValues="">
                  <nor:OrderID>11113</nor:OrderID>
                  <nor:ProductID>30</nor:ProductID>
                  <nor:UnitPrice>99.000</nor:UnitPrice>
                  <nor:Quantity>10</nor:Quantity>
                  <nor:Discount>0</nor:Discount>
               </nor:Order_x0020_Details>
            </nor:new>
         </nor:tuple>
         <nor:tuple>
            <nor:new>
               <nor:Order_x0020_Details qAccess="0" qConstraint="0" qInit="0" qValues="">
                  <nor:OrderID>11113</nor:OrderID>
                  <nor:ProductID>40</nor:ProductID>
                  <nor:UnitPrice>88.0000</nor:UnitPrice>
                  <nor:Quantity>19</nor:Quantity>
                  <nor:Discount>0</nor:Discount>
               </nor:Order_x0020_Details>
            </nor:new>
         </nor:tuple>
      </nor:UpdateOrder_x0020_Details>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two different (XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0) one-liner expressions. Complete XSLT-based verification is also provided.

Answer (score 1):

**I. XPath 2.0**

**Use this XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
   max(/*/*/*/*/*/*/nor:ProductID)
```

and, respectively:

```
   min(/*/*/*/*/*/*/nor:ProductID)
```

**II. XPath 1.0**

**Use this XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
/*/*/*/*/*/*/nor:ProductID
                   [not(. > following::nor:ProductID)
                  and
                    not(. > preceding::nor:ProductID)
                   ]
```

and, respectively:

```
/*/*/*/*/*/*/nor:ProductID
                   [not(. < following::nor:ProductID)
                  and
                    not(. < preceding::nor:ProductID)
                   ]
```

**Here is XSLT-based verification of the two solutions**:

**I. XSLT 1.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:nor="http://schemas.cordys.com/NorthwindMetadata">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  min:   <xsl:value-of select=
            "/*/*/*/*/*/*/nor:ProductID
                   [not(. > following::nor:ProductID)
                  and
                    not(. > preceding::nor:ProductID)
                   ]
     "/>
     <xsl:text>/ max: </xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "/*/*/*/*/*/*/nor:ProductID
                   [not(. &lt; following::nor:ProductID)
                  and
                    not(. &lt; preceding::nor:ProductID)
                   ]
     "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:nor="http://schemas.cordys.com/NorthwindMetadata">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <nor:UpdateOrder_x0020_Details reply="yes" commandUpdate="no" preserveSpace="no" batchUpdate="no">
            <nor:tuple>
                <nor:new>
                    <nor:Order_x0020_Details qAccess="0" qConstraint="0" qInit="0" qValues="">
                        <nor:OrderID>11113</nor:OrderID>
                        <nor:ProductID>43</nor:ProductID>
                        <nor:UnitPrice>36.0000</nor:UnitPrice>
                        <nor:Quantity>25</nor:Quantity>
                        <nor:Discount>0</nor:Discount>
                    </nor:Order_x0020_Details>
                </nor:new>
            </nor:tuple>
            <nor:tuple>
                <nor:new>
                    <nor:Order_x0020_Details qAccess="0" qConstraint="0" qInit="0" qValues="">
                        <nor:OrderID>11113</nor:OrderID>
                        <nor:ProductID>30</nor:ProductID>
                        <nor:UnitPrice>99.000</nor:UnitPrice>
                        <nor:Quantity>10</nor:Quantity>
                        <nor:Discount>0</nor:Discount>
                    </nor:Order_x0020_Details>
                </nor:new>
            </nor:tuple>
            <nor:tuple>
                <nor:new>
                    <nor:Order_x0020_Details qAccess="0" qConstraint="0" qInit="0" qValues="">
                        <nor:OrderID>11113</nor:OrderID>
                        <nor:ProductID>40</nor:ProductID>
                        <nor:UnitPrice>88.0000</nor:UnitPrice>
                        <nor:Quantity>19</nor:Quantity>
                        <nor:Discount>0</nor:Discount>
                    </nor:Order_x0020_Details>
                </nor:new>
            </nor:tuple>
        </nor:UpdateOrder_x0020_Details>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
  min:   30/ max: 43
```

**II. XSLT 2.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:nor="http://schemas.cordys.com/NorthwindMetadata">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    max: <xsl:sequence select=
     "max(/*/*/*/*/*/*/nor:ProductID)"/>
     <xsl:text>/ min: </xsl:text>
     <xsl:sequence select=
     "min(/*/*/*/*/*/*/nor:ProductID)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), again the wanted, correct answer is produced**:

```
max: 43/ min: 30
```

**Final note**: As always when having prefixed names in an XPath expression, the API of the used XPath engine must have been used to register the namespace and the binding of the prefix to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this XPath to find `nor:tuple` with max `nor:ProductID`:

```
//nor:tuple[
    not(following-sibling::nor:tuple/nor:new//nor:ProductID > nor:new//nor:ProductID 
        or 
        preceding-sibling::nor:tuple/nor:new//nor:ProductID > nor:new//nor:ProductID)
]
```

To find max value (in your example `43`):

```
//nor:tuple[
    not(following-sibling::nor:tuple/nor:new//nor:ProductID > nor:new//nor:ProductID 
        or 
        preceding-sibling::nor:tuple/nor:new//nor:ProductID > nor:new//nor:ProductID)
]/nor:new//nor:ProductID
```

To find min value, replace `>` with `<`.